# How to use typescript definition in rspec?

Tags: ruby, typescript, rspec

Context:
We have :

- A Rails backend tested with rspec as test runner.
- A Spa with typescript

We are looking for a way to test our api against typescript file definition.

For example if have the following type definition.

```
// //car.d.ts
export type Car = {
  color: String;
  max_speed: Number;
  id: Number;

};
export default Car;
```

I would love being able to write

```
// request/car_respec.rb
...

it "respect car type definition" do 
 car = ????
 car_type = {color: 12, max_speed: "170 Miles/Hour", id: 12}
 expect(car_type).to be_implemented_by(car)

end
...
```

We did tried this Active record / Typescript type mapper https://github.com/haseebeqx/tsrecord

But it does not really fit our need. :-/

Comment: I'll ask a similar question: "Why to use typescript definition in rspec?" Doing so will create a very strong coupling between your SPA and your backend. Furthermore, it is usually a backend that is the source of truth in the system, so it is your ts definition that is to follow the model, not the other way around - but even though you need to be cautious not to introduce coupling.

Comment: I could not agree more, with you withe the fact the backend have to be the source of trust of the system.  

In order to be a bit more precise the idea i have in my mind is to check the typescript definition Do respect, the backend result, not the other way around.